# An alien generational ship orbits earth and ask for resources. Should we help?

Tags: society, aliens, government

A cute cat-like Mammalian biped race has fleed the Deneb system due to a war that they lost. Their former world was similar to earth and has DNA as its genetic material. Their technology is similar to ours but they have decent energy shields. However they are starving and ask us for supplies and fuel. They would love it if we could accept their presence on our planet. In exchange they will teach us the secrets of the energy shields and share their rich alien culture and tales about their former world. Should we help them or not?

Notes : They had FTL drives but that knowledge is lost now. The crew of the ship is about one hundred thousand (100,000) individuals. They have no pathogens and they can breathe our atmosphere without problems. However they want to start their own nation on the Moon when their numbers increase.

Comment: Should we help or not is a matter of opinion.  A better phrased question would be what kinds of ramification would there be to Earth if we did help.

Comment: @Anketam I agree, but that may go into the broad range instead. VTC.

Comment: "want to start their own nation in the moon" - why then they bother us to ask, and why then they do not choose any other star system. If they can live on moon, then they can live on any moderate body in space in any star system - why here? Deny, it some kind of trickery and they endanger our species, they should have more serious arguments for our involvement in their problems, the reason they look like cute anime characters is not enough to set 7 billion humans in danger.

Comment: @MolbOrg Well they are starving refugees,And their ship is a technological reliq that allow them to live in the moon but is single use only.And earth is super populated by now,As for their nation,They just want to be free.

Comment: Why do they need resources from us, who live in a gravity well; why not just mine some asteroids, comets, etc.?

Comment: Can we eat minerals? No?

Comment: They are a problem in first place, someone dedicated enough (of a reason or not) to destroy their civilization(true or not). They look very suspicious - what they were hoping for if they can't start their civilization, they knew about our existence? There is a lot of questions they have to answer, at the moment they look very suspicious and lying. And I recommend editing your question answering possible questions of curious 7 billion people who would like not to die in a result of the decision. Clarification edits are welcome here on WB.

Comment: If they were a dog like race, man's best friend, I would help them.  However, since they are cat like, nope.  They can't be trusted.

Comment: Watch the movie (and later TV series) *Alien Nation*.

Comment: I would ask why they would want to live on the moon of all places.  I'm just curious.   Of course... we know what curiosity does to the cat(people).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

Once upon a time, people thought that people from a town did not deserve charity or solidarity. We got over that.

Once upon a time, people thought that people who speak a different language did not deserve charity or solidarity. Part of the world got over that.

Once upon a time, people thought that people with a different skin color did not deserve charity or solidarity. We haven't quite gotten over that yet, but we're working on it.

People will learn that the cat-folk are people, too, and society will be better for it.

Comment: It's more than just acceptance. You cannot just trust everyone in the world because you don't want to be xenophobic. You should be more wary of other beings. They might give us technology, but they most likely know the limitations and weak points. If they grow fast and go to war they might win and take our planet. If we were to help then we would have to take their technology and research it fast as possible. Then keep a tight grip on them by not letting them research more technologies or grow too fast.

Comment: @Masterzagh, being liberal does not mean being stupid. We *know* that there are good and evil humans, and we'd *assume* that the same applies to the aliens. That sounds smarter than assuming they're all evil.

Comment: The problem is that this is a new species we are seeing for the first time. We know nothing about them so we have to play it safe while getting to know them and their technology. I would understand your point if you were talking about humans, but unfortunately with meeting a new species there's too much that can go wrong.